# DSLCalendarView - Full line of disabled dates displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, dslcalendarview

I was just checking [**DSLCalendarView sample**](https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView)
Please see the below screenshots on running the sample

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

**Screenshot 2**

[image]

As you can see that the bottom row in 1st screenshot and top row in 2nd screenshot have been displayed although they all have other month's dates. How to fix this - Do not display the row if it has all dates of previous/next month ?
Asking this question to users who have experienced this library.

Comment: If this were my UI, I'd probably want to offer both the top and bottom rows with dates from other months in it but simply change the color and/or disable the selectability of the non-current-month days.  In any event, the source for DSLCalendarView hasn't been updated in at least three years.  There's a number of (apparently ignored) pull requests from other contributors and 34 issues / enhancements. I'd recommend also looking at some of the 93+ forks because somebody else might have done the changes you need. This may be an opportunity for somebody else, or you, to make fixes you need.

Comment: @Nitish have you check my below answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library. in library, we have **DSLCalendarDayView.m file**

goto that file and find **- (void)drawDayNumber Method** (which is written in last)

replace that method with my below method.

```
- (void)drawDayNumber {
    if (self.selectionState == DSLCalendarDayViewNotSelected) {
        [[UIColor colorWithWhite:66.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] set];
    }
    else {
        [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    }

    UIFont *textFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    CGSize textSize = [_labelText sizeWithFont:textFont];

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(ceilf(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - (textSize.width / 2.0)), ceilf(CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - (textSize.height / 2.0)), textSize.width, textSize.height);
    if(self.isInCurrentMonth)
        [_labelText drawInRect:textRect withFont:textFont];
}
```

check it with this. it will not print previous and next month date. show only current month dates.

Comment: you need to add just one condition if(self.isInCurrentMonth) before draw your day